# How to place image without text alongside in html

Tags: html, css, image, html-table

I am trying to create an invoice by modifying some existing html. I want to put an image (logo) at the top of the page and then start a table underneath it. The problem I have is that whatever I do the text in the table appears alongside the image. I have found all sorts of ideas to wrap text around an image but nothing to actually NOT wrap text around an image. Except as a caption to an image, also not what I want. Code I have is:-

```html
<style>
div.logo {float: right;}
table {width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;}
.twenty {width: 20%; }
.thirty {width: 30%; }
.fifty {width: 50%; }
</style>
<div class = "logo">
  <img align="right" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1212/3100/files/logo.png?14279783622096777710" width="30%" height="30%"><br clear="all">
</div>
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col class="fifty" />
    <col class="twenty" />
    <col class="thirty" />
  </colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Invoice Date</td>
      <td>{{ shop_name }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Date {{created_at | date: "%d/%m/%y" }}</td>
      <td>{{ shop.address }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Any help really appreciated.

What I get [Link to my invoice render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaEnz.jpg)

Comment: you want like logo should be placed right side and text should display left side but below the logo height.

Comment: What would you like the layout to look like, e.g. logo top right, table full width underneath it?

Comment: Try making the logo a block element, `display:block` if that works

Comment: Logo should be top right and then the table underneath across the full width. 3 columns 50%, 20% and 30%. Thanks

Comment: Read something about using display:block but couldn't figure out where exactly to put it in the code or maybe the syntax. Couldn't get it to work. Thanks

Comment: I couldn't see any problem with your code in regarding your expection , the logo is at the top right side , the table is beneath the logo , what else do you want ?
The table does not appear along side the texts , you need to fill the <td></td>s , Thanks and have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there wasn't any issue with your code as such, the first column of the table was just empty and you have a `width: 50%` on it from the `colgroup.fifty` style. This was making it look like the table was pushed to the right.

See the pen here with background colours to make it more clear: https://codepen.io/lauraeddy/pen/zPYKva

Comment: Thanks for that and yes that layout is what I am looking for. I know I had the first cells empty but even when I put something in it doesn't change anything. Have attached a screenshot of how mine renders as a link at the end of the original question.

Comment: Please see updated code via the link above. I have added a `width: 100%;` to the image div. It also depends how you are rendering the code, is it via printing or an online system?

Comment: Genius Laura. That fixed it. It is being rendered online as a preview in a webpage so not sure what code might be going on around it I'd have to check the source.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you are ok. The image will be placed at center of the div.

```
<div class = "logo">
  <img align="right" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1212/3100/files/logo.png?14279783622096777710" width="30%" height="30%"><br clear="all">
</div>

.logo {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
}

<div class="table">
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col class="fifty" />
    <col class="twenty" />
    <col class="thirty" />
  </colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Invoice Date</td>
      <td>{{ shop_name }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Date {{created_at | date: "%d/%m/%y" }}</td>
      <td>{{ shop.address }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>

.table {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: My guess is, if the invoice is printable, he'll have to make adjustments in print.css with flexbox.

Comment: I'll try in the morning my time. The logo wants to be right justified but I guess that just means changing the text-align and justify-content to "right". Thanks